# Como insertar contenidos una base de datos desde un formulario en php

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas quisiera saber como insertar contenido desde un formulario en PHP a una base de datos MySQL. A continuación le muestro mi código y el error que me aparece.

Este es el código del formulario:

```
<?php 
include 'menu.php';

 ?>
 <br>
 <form method="POST" action="ingresar1.php">
CEDULA:<input type="text" name="cedula"><br>
NOMBRE:<input type="text" name="nombre"><br>
APELLIDO:<input type="text" name="apellido"><br>
DIRECCION:<textarea name="direccion" rows="5" cols="25"></textarea><br>
EMAIL:<input type="text" name="email"><br>
TELEFONO:<input type="text" name="telefono"><br>
SEXO:<input type="radio" name="sexo" value="F">FEMENINO<br>
<input type="radio" name="sexo" value="M">MASCULINO<br>

<input type="submit" name="Ingresar" value="Ingresar">
<input type="reset" name="Limpiar" value="Limpiar">

 </form>
```

Este es el código del PHP que inserta los datos en la BD:

```
<?php 
include 'conexion.php';
 $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios  ('$_POST [cedula]',
                                        '$_POST [nombre]',
                                        '$_POST [apellido]',
                                        '$_POST [direccion]',
                                        '$_POST [email]',
                                        '$_POST [telefono]',
                                        '$_POST [sexo]')";
$resultado = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
echo mysqli_error($link);
if (!mysqli_error($link)) {
    ?>
    <script>
        alert ('Registro fue ingresado con exito');
    </script>
    <?php
}
else
{
    ?>
    <script>
        alert ('ERROR: El registro no fue almacenado');
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=ingresar.php">
```

Luego de enviar los datos me sale esto:

[image: luego de enviar los datos me sale esto..]

Le doy aceptar y me sale esto:

[image: le doy aceptar y me sale esto..]

pero He visto el código y no se cual pueda ser mi error.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios  ('$_POST [cedula]', ¿Terminas así la línea anterior?

Comment: no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. el codigo esta tal cual en la pregunta amigo.

Comment: Bien, pues tienes entonces que revisar esa línea. Tiene errores de sintaxis básicos.

Comment: puedes poner la estructura de la tabla usuarios de tu bbdd para poder ayudarte con esa línea?

Comment: cedula int(8) primary
nombre varchar (15)
apellido varchar (15)
direccion varchar (100)
email varchar (25)
telefono varchar (15)
sexo char (1)
 esa es la extructura amigo pero no se cual pueda ser el error de sintaxis ahi..

Comment: Para empezar quita todos los espacios que hay entre `$_POST` y el corchete de apertura `[`. También, el nombre de cada clave debe ir entre comillas. Deben quedar todos así por ejemplo `$_POST["cedula"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con esto a ver:

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_nombre = 'database_name';
$db_usuario = 'root';
$db_clave = '';

$conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_clave, $db_nombre);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "fallo";
    exit();
}

$conexion->set_charset("utf8");

$consulta = "INSERT INTO usuarios(cedula, nombre, apellido, direccion, email, telefono, sexo) VALUES ('" . $_POST[cedula] . "','" . $_POST[nombre] . "','" .  $_POST[apellido] . "','" .  $_POST[direccion] . "','" .  $_POST[email] . "','" .  $_POST[telefono] . "','" .  $_POST[sexo] . "')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
?>
```

Comment: de este modo si me funciono tan solo cambie la parte de la consulta y funciono perfecto gracias..!

Answer (score 0):

Podrias mover los $_POST a variables y luego realizar el insert

```
$cedula   = $_POST['cedula'];
$nombre   = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'] ;
$direccion = $_POST['direccion'] ;
$email     = $_POST['email'] ;
$telefono   = $_POST['telefono'] ;
$sexo      = $_POST['sexo'] ;

 $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios  values ( '$cedula', '$nombre', '$apellido', '$direccion', '$email', '$telefono', '$sexo' )" ;
 echo $sql ;                 
if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    echo "Registro insertado correctamente";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=ingresar.php">
```

Comment: Ejemplo de insert (mas seguro) https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp

Answer (score 0):

Explicación de las respuestas dadas:

El error es bastante explícito "Array to string conversion"

Al poner un espacio entre `$_POST` y el índice que queres referenciar, toma el array (`$_POST`es un array) y trata de convertirlo a string (en el sql te queda como la palabra "Array").

Luego el espacio y el índice se toman literales, es por eso que el sql queda medio bizarro: "`Array [cedula]', 'Array [nombre]'`", etc...

Si quitas los espacios entre `$_POST`y el `[`, seguramente te aparecerá otro error/warning: al referenciar `$_POST[nombre]` php encuentra que `nombre` no es una constante y se asume el valor `"nombre"`, para evitar esto ponele `$_POST["nombre"]`.

Lo cual significa: el valor de la clave `nombre` en el array `$_POST`